# Taking simple user input inside a method in Bot Framework

Tags: c#, botframework, azure-language-understanding

Is there a simple way I can have a user message in Microsoft Bot Framework passed into a string variable (c#)?

Essentially, I want to take the next user message as an input half way through a method and continue the execution of the same method with the message stored as a variable.

I want to avoid the process of using PromptDialog, modifying the enclosing method to fit the PromptDialog parameters (since my method will have LuisResult and not IAwaitable...), etc.

What I want is the equivalent of taking user inputs through the console, but in this case I would be doing it through the bot framework interface - without exiting or modifying the method I'm in currently. Nothing fancy is needed, like retries, etc.

EDIT: I don't want/need the message to go through LUIS either (MessageReceived also puts each message through LUIS)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way of currently doing it. Bots have to be stateless all the state of the bot must be explicitly maintained in `IBotDataBag`. What you are hoping to do will essentially create an anonymous method that references local variables. The resulting closure is not serializable.

Comment: So is there a way to handle PromptDialogs whilst maintaining the Luisresult variable? My issue would be resolved if I could pass control to a method but also have access to my LuisResult result variable (a private global instance of it gives me trouble because of serialization). Thanks

Comment: The Message class has three properties you can use for that: BotUserData, BotConversationData, BotPerUserInConversationData. You can find more details here: http://docs.botframework.com/connector/tracking-bot-state/#message-botdata-properties